# javascript variable empty declaration or object

Tags: javascript, object

I know i'm most probably nitpicking but... i have the following code:

```
var book;
var i=0;

i = 300;    
book = new CBook();
book.Title = "blahblah";
book.Contents = "lalalala";


function CBook() {
    this.Title = "";
    this.Contents = "";
}
```

now my question is:

would it be better to have

```
var book = {};
```

instead of

```
var book;
```

in the first version typeof(book) returns undefined before the assignment book = new CBook();

thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> would it be better to have
>
> ```
> var book = {};
> ```

No, for a couple of reasons:

1. You'd be creating an object just to throw it away when you did `book = new Book(...)` later. (Of course, a *really good* JavaScript engine might realize that and optimize it out. But still...)
2. If you use `lint` tools, you'd be actively preventing them from warning you that you attempt to use `book` before you (properly) initialize it.
3. If for some reason you had logic in your code that needed to check whether you'd assigned a book yet, you'd lose the ability to do that. By leaving the variable with its default `undefined` value, that check can be `if (!book) { /* Not assigned yet */ }`. (Of course, naive lint tools may warn you about that, too.)

#2 goes for the `= 0` in `var i = 0;` as well.

But if you feel strongly about initializing `book` at the declaration, `null` would probably be a better choice.

Comment: ... and also loose a simple way to check, if the `book` object exists before it's created.

Answer (score 2):

A variable should be declared closest to its first use.  So, if I were you, I would change to:

```
var book = new CBook();
```

Also, I would pass parameters to CBook and use it as a constructor:

```
var book = new CBook("blahblah", "lalalala");

function CBook(title, contents) {
   this.title = title;
   this.contents = contents;
}
```

Comment: Not necessary at all, all variable declarations are hoisted. Hence if you do this in the middle of the code, `var book; ` is executed at the beginning of the code anayway.

Comment: Hoisting happens within JS engine, the recommendation is for code readability.

Comment: i like declaring all variables in the beginning of every function

Comment: @WandMaker I think recommendations depend on the recommendator ; ).

Comment: Almost all coding conventions are aimed at creating readable and maintainable code.  So, anything done with intention of making code more readable should be preferred.

Comment: @WandMaker: Indeed. Such as putting all variable declarations at the beginning of the scope in which they're used. See? Your "readable" and my "readable" don't match. :-) Of course, in practice, functions should be so short that "at the beginning of the function" **is** "close to first use" and the issue goes away. (Along with a lot of other ones.)

Comment: @MIrrorMirror: You can still declare `book` at the beginning of the function. Just declare it `var book = new CBook()`. Indeed, it is also better to declare `var i = 300`. That's what initializers are for.

Comment: @TJ, I just referred back to Douglas Crockford's conventions.  It seems for Java Script declaring variables at the top is recommended for altogether different reasons.  Anyways, point taken.

Comment: @WandMaker: Well, yes, there's that issue as well. :-)